# Does APK/res content change to a new structure after updating AGP 7.0.2?

Tags: android

Recently, I've found the APK/res content has changed into a new structure:

[image]

It doesn't reflect what I see from the res directory of my Android Studio project:

[image]

My app has just updated Android Gradle Plugin 7.0.2 and targetSdkVersion 31 recently. I'm not very sure if it relates to either AGP 7.0.2 or targetSdkVersion 31. But when I downgrade Android Gradle Plugin to 4.0.1, the APK/res content returns back to the normal form.

So, my question is, what makes the APK/res content looks like in the first image? Is it a form of encryption?

**Note:**

- I used 7zip and Android Studio to view the content of APK, and both of them show the same result for APK/res as the first image.
- But when I used Apktool.jar to decompose the APK, I see the APK/res directory content is in the normal form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a new task [OptimizeResourcesTask] add in default ,

we could close it by add following in root gradle.properties

android.enableResourceOptimizations = false